# ModelChoiceField - get request.user.username

Tags: django, database, sqlite, model-view-controller, orm

I need to choose User to form by the request.user.username and save into the database.
Here I have a code of **forms.py**

```
class Send(forms.ModelForm):
  sender = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.order_by('username')
```

Here is the **models.py**, where I am going to save the data about the user:

```
class SendM(models.Model):
 sender = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And here is **views.py**, where I get the data

```
def form_create(request):
   if not request.user.is_anonymous:
        form = Send(request.POST or None, initial={'sender': request.user.username})

   if request.method == "POST":
      if form.is_valid():
         send = SendM(sender=User.objects.get(username=form.cleaned_data['sender']))
      send.save()
      return redirect("/")
```

To understand I want to pre-filled the array with the user found in database.

Thank you very much!!

it does only this:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XY2fl.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial value in the form is the user reference, not the username, because you're using a `ModelChoiceField`. I don't really remember now if it's the model instance (`initial={'sender': request.user})` or the model primary key (`initial={'sender': request.user.pk})` .

Then after `form.is_valid()`, there is no need to get the user from the database again. You just need to call the save method on the form. Django does the rest.

```py
if form.is_valid():
    send = form.save()
```

Comment: Thanks. It is what I have had looking for :)